# How do I change code in DEVELOPER tab?

Tags: developer, reports

How do I change the code in Developer tab in CiviCRM reports?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by changing the code in the Developer tab? That would probably make it a little easier to help you. And I do not think you can change the developer code, it think it is only there to help you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I thought it is there meant to be building custom layouts for reports. My goal was to do complex database queries not possible via standard reports or searches.

Comment: I thought so. You should focus on building an extension, that will allow you to customize reports and do complex database queries. Have you heard about extensions and studied the CiviCRM wiki page instructions?